# Display copy if threshold met

Tags: jquery

So on an ecommerce site, theres a listing page which has lots of products and each contain a price in £'s which are stored in divs called **.pri** under each products container called **.productListItem**.

If that value of a product is over £120 I want to append some text to the **.pri** div of each product, else if it's under £120 for a product do nothing.

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

```js
var price = ($('.productListItem .itemPrice .pri').text()).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  
if (price >= '120') {    
$( '.productListItem .itemPrice .pri' ).append( '<div class="FDbadging">+FREE DELIVERY</div>' );
} else {

}
```

Any help please?

Comment: have a look at `$.each`

Comment: @Alex thanks but I tried initially adding **$('.productListItem .itemPrice .pri').each(function(i, obj) {** to the begining initially but nothing happens still so I removed it to post here just because if I also add an **else** statement to the else if it runs the else statement whether it's above or below the threshold. So something must be wrong in the statement I posted above to determine the threshold. I Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/j24udwfn/

```js
$('.productListItem .itemPrice .pri').each( function(){
  var price = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
alert(price);
  if (price <= 119) {
$(this).siblings('.FDbadging').remove();
  } else {
$(this).append('<div class="FDbadging">+FREE DELIVERY</div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is getting somewhere, it's now adding the message under every product now no matter what the threshold sadly but what it's doing is duplicating that message under each product the exact amount of products that are over the threshold (see image example: https://ibb.co/dLgrD5 6 products are over the threshold on this page), so it is detecting products over the threshold somewhere

Comment: I made a few adjustments and tested in jsFiddle

Comment: amazing thank you, those adjustments nailed it, glad to know I wasn't miles off (even if I did paste the wrong code in initially) you knew what I was aiming for :D

Answer (score 1):

**try this code**

```
$('.productListItem .itemPrice .pri').each(function(){
var subTotal = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
if (subTotal <= 119) {
$(this).siblings('.FDbadging').remove();
} else {
   $(this).append( '<div class="FDbadging">+FREE DELIVERY</div>' );
}
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k82bf5Lh/3/)

Comment: Pretty much same as above, tested it and works great thanks